# Apple Updater (Windows) Won't Download Updates?

Tags: software-update, windows, auto-update

I have an update for iTunes and iCloud yet neither will download. It downloads less than a megabyte but hangs up. My internet connection is fine and very fast. What is going on?

Note: I am on Windows 8.1 64bit.

Comment: check this out http://support.apple.com/en-us/HT203206

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am going to assume this was a temporary problem with Apple. The update recently installed without an issue and was very quick.